# Norm function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, norm

How can I take easily norm of an array?

I tried this and I have an error:

> too many initializers error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert
>   from 'cv::OutputArray (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'double'

```
double DaisyFeature [200];
double DaisyFeature1 [200];

double norm( DaisyFeature , DaisyFeature1 , NORM_L2,noArray);
```

I think the problem is something about initializing but I don't know what should I use instead of `double DaisyFeature [200];`

Answer (score 7):

The documentation is pretty clear on how Input/OutputArrays work. The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray).

It basicly states that you can assume that any algorithm implemented by openCV accepts the following types as input (and output);

> cv::Mat, std::vector<>, cv::Matx<>, cv::Vec<> or cv::Scalar

Answer (score 4):

Use an std::vector instead of arrays:

```
std::vector<double> DaisyFeature(200);
std::vector<double> DaisyFeature1(200);

norm( DaisyFeature , DaisyFeature1 , NORM_L2,noArray);
```